# Objective C: releasing objects basic questions (non-ARC)

Tags: ios, autorelease, objective-c-2.0

I have two rookie questions about memory management in non-ARC project without GC:
in Objective C,when I 'autorelease' object and return it from method, should I 'release' it in the "parent method" calling the method retuning the object?

The second question is, that I returned object (f.e. *user*) from method (instance method on another object, f.e. *userService*) and saved it to property (*self.userProp*, *self* instantiated the object *userService* and called his method). When I released the object *userService* (whose method returned the object *user*, stored in property *self.userProp*), it released also the object stored in property (object *user* stored in property *self.userProp*). Why? Who was the owner of the object in property?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when I 'autorelease' object and return it from method, should I
>   'release' it in the "parent method" calling the method retuning the
>   object?

No.  Here's why.  Let's layout an example exactly as you've said:

```
-(NSObject*)someMethodThatReturnsAnAutoreleasedObject {
    return [[[NSObject alloc]init]autorelease];
}

-(void)myMethod {
    NSObject *obj = [self someMethodThatReturnsAnAutoreleasedObject];
    [obj doSomething];
    [obj release] //PROBLEM!
}
```

Look at the retain count of the objects step by step, and you'll see that while the `-autorelease` may not immediately cause an issue for you, it will at some later date (because `-autorelease`'d objects aren't "auto-released", rather they are deallocated en masse when their owning pool is drained or deallocated).  The method that returns an autoreleased object returns it with an eventual retain count of 0 (0 (start) + 1 (alloc) - 1 (autorelease)), so you releasing it is not only unnecessary, but will cause a crash.

> The second question is, that I returned object (f.e. user) from method
>   (instance method on another object, f.e. userService) and saved it to
>   property (self.userProp, self instantiated the object userService and
>   called his method). When I released the object userService (whose
>   method returned the object user, stored in property self.userProp), it
>   released also the object stored in property (object user stored in
>   property self.userProp). Why? Who was the owner of the object in
>   property?

Again, a little setup first (this is rather convoluted at first, but makes complete sense afte you see what you're doing).

```
-(NSUserService*)someMethodThatReturnsAnAutoreleasedObject {
    return [[[NSUserService alloc]init]autorelease];
}

-(void)myMethod {
    self.userservice = [self someMethodThatReturnsAnAutoreleasedObject];
    [obj doSomething];
    [obj release] //No problem, assuming userService is declared retain or strong.
}
```

Well, why is this different?  Memory qualifiers, that's why!  When you declare a property, you declare a set of memory qualifiers to tell the compiler what kind of modifier to append to the assignment sign.  Most properties are declared `retain` or strong ((under ARC), and hopefully your `userService` one is declared as such, as well) if they are object types, which makes the compiler interpret

```
self.userservice = [self someMethodThatReturnsAnAutoreleasedObject];
```

as

```
self.userservice = [[self someMethodThatReturnsAnAutoreleasedObject]retain];
```

Therefore, you must release it, or you have a leak on your hands (0 (start) + 1 (alloc) - 1 (autorelease) + 1 (retain) = +1).

Comment: Thanks, I have some mess in my code. Your explanation is great and in my test console app it's working like a charm.